# Main Motivation behind the use of identity of $(a+b)^3$ ,so as to solve cubic equations using Cardons Method

Tags: cubics

Whats so special about the identity $(a+b)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + 3ab(a+b)$ which gave Cardano the clever idea to invent a method to solve cubic depressed equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you have a depressed cubic equation, such as

$$x^3 + bx + c = 0.$$

After (apparent) centuries, Cardano (or somebody) got clever.  They reasoned that you could set

$$x = (s + t)$$

and **add** a second constraint that $3st = -b.$

This meant that

$$s^3 + t^3 + 3st(x) + bx + c = 0. \tag1 $$

However, because of the artificial but valid constraint that $3st = -b$, equation (1) above implies that

$$s^3 + t^3 + c = 0. \tag2 $$

That is, because of this artifical constraint, the $x$ term has **vanished**.

Equation (2) above implies that

$$s^3 + \left[\frac{-b}{3s}\right]^3 + c = 0. \tag3 $$

In (3) above, multiplying each term by $(s^3)$ converts the equation into a quadratic equation in $(s^3).$

Comment: Can this same /similar additional  constraint term be applied to reduced quadratics/pentic/hextic equations?

Comment: @Orion_Pax My knowledge of Field Theory (especially Galois Theory) is practically non-existent.  Once Cardano did his thing, over the next few centuries, something similar was done for quartic equations.  Then, during this period, the professional Mathematicians thought that a similar method should work on quintic equations.  In the late 1700's and early 1800's, it was discovered (i.e. proven) that this presumption is **false**.  Personally, my understanding of the Math in this area is very hazy.  The question that you are asking really involves Galois Theory.

Comment: @Orion_Pax I suspect that it would be quite a challenge for any Galois Theory guru to provide an explanation, in $500$ words or less of intuitively why there is no  general solution to the quintic equation.  Your comment/question has gone well beyond my knowledge.

Comment: I see its okay i have got a good idea how it was made useful like for cubic , i will try to search out for other degrees . Thanks for your wonderful explanation